# How do I create a 32 bit installer with WiX using jpackage

Tags: windows, wix, jpackage

I'm packaging a 32 bit JVM and Java appliation using Java 14 jpackage which in turn uses WiX.

I can successfully create an .msi installer but it appears to be a 64 bit app that
does not even start on 32 bit Windows 7.

So how do I create a 32 bit .msi installer?

AFAIU jpackage creates all the config files for Wix but according to the jpackage output I can
customise some of them, here is the output from jpackage which hints at that possibility.

Using default package resource WinLauncher.template [Template for creating executable properties file] (add TestApp.properties to the resource-dir to customize)
Using default package resource main.wxs [Main WiX project file] (add main.wxs to the resource-dir to customize).
Using default package resource overrides.wxi [Overrides WiX project file] (add overrides.wxi to the resource-dir to customize).

I've googled high and low but I cannot find the answers.

I tried something like this (among other things):

file: overrides.wxi

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
<?define Win64 = "no" ?>
</Include>
```

But that did not make a difference.

I'm pretty sure this is simple but I cannot figure this out.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work?

Comment: No I did not get it to work